# Opening/Importing 147 GIG CSV

Tags: sql-server, database, csv

I have a CSV file with 350 million records and 350 Columns.. I have tried to import it to a Local MSSQL Database but I keep getting the following error:

> Msg 4866, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
>       The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator
>   are specified correctly.
>       Msg 7301, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>       Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

This is the code I was using to import the data

```
BULK INSERT TABLE_NAME_HERE
FROM 'C:\PATH_TO_FILE\FILE_NAME.csv'
WITH
(
  FIRSTROW = 2,
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

Can anyone please help me and point me in the right direction to work with these type of files?

Comment: We cannot judge whether your bulk insert is correct unless we have more information about the structure of the source file.

Comment: I am installing CigWing on the computer so I can open the file and post information about it..